# when i type _ (underscore) in my search form based on php , why results still come out?

Tags: php

```
$i_name  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['search']);

$search_item = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemname LIKE '%$i_name%' ORDER by 1 DESC LIMIT 5";
$find_item  =  mysqli_query($con,$search_item);
$count_item =  mysqli_num_rows($find_item);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `_` is a wildcard character for 1 character https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: Read about `LIKE`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: Or try `LIKE '%{$i_name}%'`. This will allow PHP to better process the variable name.

Comment: why did you go and add boldness in an edit?

Comment: obviously fallen onto deaf ears

Comment: sorry its my first time here asking question, i didnt knew the syntax.  but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underscore is a special character in the SQL like syntax
It means match any one character, you'll have to escape it with a `\`, you might also want to escape `%` as well.

```
$i_name = str_replace(["_","%"], ["\_","\%"], $i_name);
```

Answer (score 4):

`%` is a wildcard to match an arbitrary number of characters (including zero characters). `_` is a wildcard to match any single character.

So your LIKE evaluates to: *an arbitrary number of characters followed by any single character followed by an arbitrary number of characters*.  Which is anything that contains one or more characters.

You need to escape wildcards in `$i_name` using `\%` and `\_`.

See [MySQL Pattern Matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: oops my bad, sometimes we forgets some basic rules.

Comment: Check mark icon under the voting buttons https://stackoverflow.com/tour